# Split an array from nested array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to separate an array from a nested array.Any help would be appreciated.

Nested array:

```
array:1 [▼
  "empid" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "IDE023"
    1 => "IDE025"
  ]
]
```

I want to split the below array from that

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "IDE023"
  1 => "IDE025"
]
```

How can i do that using PHP ?

Comment: $new_array  = $original_array[1]['empid"'];

Comment: Seriously, it should not be that simple. What's the catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_pop`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

```
$yourArray = array_pop($yourArray);
```

Note this will disturb the original array. Use only if don't want to use the original array again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$split_array = $original_array['empid'];
```